# Integrating office 365 api

Tags: c#

I am new to bot development. I am using bot framework and Visual C# to develop my bot. When I integrate my application with the office365 API, I encountered the problem with my domain. The error is my account doesn't have the access to the particular domain.Even though I signed with the global administrator account of that domain I got the same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by deleting my all the accounts.(In visual studio go to file-> Account settings).Then I signed up for the account.Because there were 2 accounts in the VisualStudio's account.So I delete the previous accounts and signup for the account.